# Possible Windows 10 Malware

Tags: windows, malware, spyware

**Data:**

There are a set of Windows 10 computers. Out of 8 of those computers, three were found to have had the Windows OS altered in an unexpected way.

An advanced malware/spyware infection is suspected.

The three computers are on different networks. None of them have the ability of communicating with each other over the local network. All of them are set to automatically receive and install updates from Microsoft.

These suspected "infections" start on December 6, with the most recent being today.

The unexpected alterations were discovered after a computer which is always on with its display always on as well, was found with its display off.

It was initially believed Windows update had automatically installed the major 10.1 update, thereby causing the changes. Upon closer inspection, such an update had not been installed. Even worse, two systems which were verified to have previously been updated to 10.1 were found to have somehow downgraded themselves back to 10.0.

Most or all of the changes were reported by the event logs to have been made by 'Kernel-General' as the source.

All of the effected systems have the following similar characteristics:

1 - All of the event logs start only at the point of suspected infection for each. There is no event log data from before this point.

2 - The event logs show exact or similar logging data on all effected systems, including Event ID 26 for a one-time boot sequence (this is normally used by a legitimate Windows Update as well).

3 - Access histories were cleared in the registry.

4 - Some interactive system menus appear to be of the Windows 10.1 style (dark background, white text).

5 - New drivers and services were installed.

6 - Existing users were added to the system as if they were new.

**Question:**

What is happening here?

Comment: What's your threat model? Who might want to attack these computers, and what would their aim be?

Comment: The firm who has leased these systems which we maintain and administer provides financial accounting and auditing services to a variety of international defense contractors. The firm itself has no real sensitive data, and everything is related to public sector accounts, and that data can be obtained through FOI anyways. In sum, quite boring really.

Comment: I think you should probably send the information that you have for all systems to Microsoft Security.  I'm not sure how we'll be able to help you as you've provided no information about what registry entries have changed, system information, types of users added, etc.  Even then this really isn't the right forum for this type of issue.

Comment: @RoraΖ: We thank you for your valuable input. You are fully entitled to your own opinions.

Comment: "New drivers and services were installed"?  Can you say anything more specifically about those? There's a good chance that they are either (a) elements of malware newly installed, or (b) elements of legitimate software that's been upgraded and just released by the maker(probably for the purpose of working better with Windows 10).  If you could provide more info about the new services/devices that might be helpful.

Comment: The log & history data vanishing is certainly cause for concern. But, FWIW, in my experience upgrading machines to Windows 10, and applying cumulative monthly Win 10 bug-fix updates and the November "Fall Update", more than a couple rather bizarre, very unexpected issues/bugs have cropped up here & there.  (Although nothing directly related to logs disappearing.) So I would be a bit surprised but not *shocked* if the cause of what your describe turned out to be non-malicious.

Comment: Also the definitive way to tell if a PC has the Nov. update is to go to Settings-->System-->About. In the About panel you'll see that the version is 1511 and the build is 10586.  The nomenclature "10.1" isn't being used by MS (for some reason).

Comment: @halfinformed: We had quite a few people look over the systems in question and they have posed similar possibilities as you have. They think the cause may not be malicious, but in fact, Microsoft and its ridiculous update methods. Everyone is however very surprised at the missing log files. It is as if the systems were only operational from that day on and not before. The log files have caused concern more than anything else.

Comment: @halfinformed: Our worse case scenario is that a competitor somehow tricked our systems into getting contaminated updates by redirection or interception. Either of those methods would require significant knowledge and investment, particularly in obtaining Microsoft's original source code, tampering with it, compiling it, signing it, then having a Windows system download those updates and believe the updates came from Microsoft. Not a very easy thing to do.

Comment: @Darth Micro Yeah, that scenario certainly seems unlikely, to say the least. Off-hand, the only attacks of that degree of sophistication re. hijacking Windows Updates (that has become public knowledge, anyway) has been done by NSA attacks against Iran. (Not Stuxnet, but related malware used in other operations.) And they did some original crypto work to forge MS's signatures on update files. Beyond-high-end stuff.

Comment: Actually, I can plausibility imagine some sophisticated attacker trying to hit you with targeted attacks on the theory that if they can get into your clients's systems they might be able to gain some financial information that could provide some insight into what classified stuff the defense contractors are up to. (An attacker might not know in advance that there's perhaps nothing worth stealing anywhere involved here.) But this smells like something else is likely going on. But of course the responsible thing is to do what you're doing and thoroughly investigate.

Comment: Windows 10 patches can change absolutely any setting you may have. That's the likely cause.